# How to delete multiple rows in both datagrid and database?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, sqlconnection

I would like to delete multiple rows in my datagrid and also in database but I'm even having problems with deleting multiple rows even in datagrid...
I can delete one row with my code (only from datagrid) but it's not enough.

I was trying to use this:

```cs
var grid = StudentsDataGrid;
var mygrid = StudentsDataGrid;

        if (grid.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            for (int i = grid.SelectedItems.Count -1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                mygrid.Items.Remove(grid.SelectedItems[i]);
            };
        }

        grid = mygrid;
```

but I recieved an error stating that operation is incorrect when ItemsSource is being used. Instead use access to elements and change them through ItemsControl.ItemsSource.

My method is only working for one row:

```cs
private void RemoveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
         Student student = StudentsDataGrid.SelectedItem as Student;
         StudentsList.Remove(student);
}
```

Maybe I should change the way I link my database to datagrid.
This is the part where I read database

```
OpenConection();
using (SqlDataReader dr = DataReader("SELECT IdStudent, FirstName, LastName, Address, IndexNumber, Name FROM apbd.Student INNER JOIN apbd.Studies ON Student.IdStudies = Studies.IdStudies"))
                {
                    list = new ObservableCollection<Student>();
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        string idstudent = dr["IdStudent"].ToString();
                        string firstname = dr["FirstName"].ToString();
                        string lastname = dr["LastName"].ToString();
                        string address = dr["Address"].ToString();
                        string index = dr["IndexNumber"].ToString();
                        string studies = dr["Name"].ToString();

                        if (dr["IdStudent"] != DBNull.Value)
                        {
                            int? emp = (int?)dr["IdStudent"];
                        }

                    list.Add(new Student
                    {
                            IdStudent = idstudent,
                            Imie = firstname,
                            Nazwisko = lastname,
                            Adres = address,
                            Index = index,
                            Studia = studies,                       
                        });

                    }
                }
            CloseConnection();
            return list;
        }
```

and in main class I'm linking it to DataGrid through ItemsSource:

```cs
public void LoadDataToDataGrid()
        {
            StudentsList = new ObservableCollection<Student>();

            var instance = new StudentsDbService();
            StudentsList = instance.ShowData();
            StudentsDataGrid.ItemsSource = StudentsList;

        }
```

Ok, I guess I've found a way of deleting multiple rows in datagrid:

```cs
private void RemoveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ObservableCollection<Student> itemsToRemove = new ObservableCollection<Student>();

            foreach (Student item in StudentsDataGrid.SelectedItems)
            {
                itemsToRemove.Add(item);
            }
            foreach (Student item in itemsToRemove)
            {
                ((ObservableCollection<Student>)StudentsDataGrid.ItemsSource).Remove(item);
            }
        }
```

but now how can I delete specific records from database?
Should I pass the IdStudent which was passed before as one of values in Student Object?

Guess I've found a way but please do tell me how bad it is?

This is the modified part responsible for removing records from DataGrid:

```cs
private void RemoveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ObservableCollection<Student> itemsToRemove = new ObservableCollection<Student>();
            List<string> studentID = new List<string>();

            foreach (Student item in StudentsDataGrid.SelectedItems)
            {
                itemsToRemove.Add(item);
                studentID.Add(item.IdStudent);
            }
            foreach (Student item in itemsToRemove)
            {
                ((ObservableCollection<Student>)StudentsDataGrid.ItemsSource).Remove(item);
            }
            var instance = new StudentsDbService();
            instance.deleteRecords(studentID);
        }
```

And this is the part when I remove records from database:

```cs
public void deleteRecords(List<string> studentID)
        {
            OpenConection();
            foreach (string item in studentID)
            {
                ExecuteQueries("DELETE FROM apbd.Student WHERE IdStudent=" + item);
            }

            CloseConnection();
        }
```

Comment: There is a lot of code and a lot of questions there.  Most people are going to pass on helping you.  Maybe start with one snippet of code and a single specific question.

Comment: Why upvote?! Use proper MvvM for this, manipulate the underlying collection instead of getting it from UI! Selected Items that you get could be marked as Deleted (a bool property) then your View could filter the Deleted items out. This way you can undo if there was a mistake made by user. I would also avoid deleting the records in db and instead mark them as Deleted (user, date, etc ...).